# Running Apache and Nginx on separate GCP Project and using the same Domain

Tags: apache, nginx, google-cloud-platform

Is this possible? Both also use different web frameworks (PHP and Flask) and databases (MySQL and PostgreSQL). And as mentioned, we are planning to use the same domain but the routing will be different.

```
Ex:
www.domain.com/project1/...
www.domain.com/project2/...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [it's possible](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts). Because you use the same domain, you have to use the same [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https), in one project (let's say in project1). Then you have to define the backends

- The loadbalancer backend for the project1 can be a managed/unmanaged instance group or a NEG
- The project 2 need to be peered in a subnet in Project1. The loadbalancer backend for the project2 is a [NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs) on the peering range.

Comment: Does your answer still apply if we were to use Apache to both our projects?

Comment: I don't see where an issue can occur.